# Xcode 6 sizing issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I created a new project in Xcode 6(single view) when I build it to simulator for iPhone 5 it works fine but when I build it to an iPod touch 5th gen it sizes like iPhone 4 (320, 480). What went wrong? how can I fix it. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Is the iPod touch running iOS 8?

Comment: It sounds like a problem with your launch images. But then I don't understand why it would affect the iPod only, and I would expect it to show up on iOS 7, not iOS 8.